# GCC on Windows: Using Address Sanitizer

Tags: c++, gcc, linker-errors, address-sanitizer

I'm using [WinLibs](https://winlibs.com/) standalone build of GCC and MinGW-w64 for Windows.
When I add `-fsanitize=address` compiler option, I get a linker error for `asan` library.

Here is the command line which I'm using to compile my program:

```
g++ -fsanitize=address -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++20 .\test.cpp
```

And here is the error:

```
C:/sw/gcc-13.1.0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lasan: No such file or directory
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I resolve this linker error?

Comment: A quick search tells it that it seems sanitizers are not supported by GCC on Windows.

Comment: I 've read, but I have not tried, MSYS2's recent clangs have asan working.

Comment: In WSL2 with GCC 11.0, I’m able to use the sanitizer

Comment: "In WSL2 with GCC 11.0, I’m able to use the sanitizer" Well in WSL2 you just run Linux executables as is on top of a Linux kernel. It's just Linux for (most) intents and purposes. Windows, on the other hand, is not.

Comment: *In WSL2 with GCC 11.0, I’m able to use the sanitizer*  Excellent!  Congratulations on a getting address sanitizer to work on Windows — that's exactly how I would have done it.

Comment: Not sure why GCC has not ported the sanitizers on Window.